# Margin between two boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css

First, I'm a newbie on front-end development. I just want to hear about possible "professional" solutions of my problem from professionals.

Now, firstly check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SB7yR/

Here is what I want: create two boxes on each row. I can't do that right here because I want to make margin between two boxes too.

I have solutions for that situation for example create a class like "last" and give it `margin-right: 0;` then apply it last boxes for each row. But I don't want to do that. It sounds .. hmm.. an amateur solution.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Side note, You have multiple IDs of `#address-box` which is invalid. IDs are unique.

Comment: Thanks for advice @AndrewClody It was just for jsfiddle. But thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `text-align: justify;` to `.addresses` and remove the `margin-right` on `address_box`.

```
.addresses {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

also, you should use a class for `.addresses #address-box` instead of an ID. ID's are supposed to be unique on a page, so only one element is allowed to have a particular ID. Use this instead `.addresses .address-box`.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/SB7yR/1/ (also under IE<9). And you noticed the duplicated ids.

Comment: Haha I got it. Thanks again for your attention @Brewal

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:-

```css
.addresses #address-box {
    height: 123px;
    width: 298px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
#address-box:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right:0;
  }
```

Comment: It just won't work in IE8, if you care about that. http://caniuse.com/#search=nth

Comment: To add to @Nitesh, I would recommend placing an `overflow:hidden;` to `#addresses-wrap`.

Comment: @Shivam I don't see in which case this would be useful ?

Comment: #Brewal,  the height of the parent div aka `#addresses-wrap` will not expand.. i.e **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SB7yR/7/)** . Setting `overflow:hidden;` will fix that issue.

Comment: @Shivam did you understand the problem there?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to make a class for all boxes (assuming each box would be the same size), then float all the boxes left. You would then make the width (in actual physical size or percentage) to be less than the width of the containing div. This would accomplish you having two boxes in each row. Hope this helps.

```
.box{ float:left; width:48%; margin-right:5px; }
```

Something like that. Experiment with the margin right amount.

Answer (score 2):

for cross browser compatibility, how about an additional html element:

http://jsfiddle.net/SB7yR/8/

html:

```
<div id="addresses-wrap">
    <div class="addresses">
        <div class="overflow">
            <div id="address-box"></div>
            <div id="address-box"></div>
            <div id="address-box"></div>
            <div id="address-box"></div>
            <div id="address-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#addresses-wrap {
    width: 620px;
    height: auto;
    border:1px solid green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.addresses {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.addresses .overflow {
    width:650px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.addresses #address-box {
    height: 123px;
    width: 298px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: with the added bonus of working in all browsers, all the way down to 6 (if required).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a float to make this work. Try replacing your `.addresses #address-box` definition with the following:

```css
.addresses #address-box {
    height: 123px;
    width: 288px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
  }
```